# Using Slack API for Adding Bookmarks in a Channel Programmatically

Tags: slack, slack-api

I can add bookmarks in a Slack channel manually, by clicking on "Add Bookmark". I will be prompted for the link, as shown in the below modal:

[image]

I wish to add this via the [Slack API methods](https://api.slack.com/methods), but I cannot seem to find an API for this. Has Slack published an API for this? If not, is there a way to do this via other methods in the Slack API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Update:**

As of March,2022

 Slack have officially launched APIs for bookmarks

- Documentation: https://api.slack.com/apis/bookmarks-api

**API for Adding Bookmarks in slack channel**

 https://api.slack.com/methods/bookmarks.add

*Earlier:
Currently slack does not have any publicly exposed methods for adding bookmarks.

 Internally, slack uses `https://**slackdomain**.slack.com/api/bookmarks.add` 
 along with form data & browser cookies, to add new bookmarks.*

Comment: This was added in February 2022 as an official API! https://api.slack.com/apis/bookmarks-api